# Multiple SQL instance on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm preparing a migration plan to migrate on-premises SQL Server to Azure. On our on-prem there are two sql instance (*DevSQL01\Dev and DevSQL01\Demo*) running on single VM. Can we create a same scenario on azure, i.e. can we create two SQL instance on a single Auzure SQL VM or is their any other option?

I know i can create a windows VM on Auzre and install SQL Server and create two instance manually, but i like to find out options like managed instance, elastic pool, etc.. has the feature to host named instance by default.

*Forgive me if this is noob question, I just started exploring cloud technologies.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On all flavors of Azure SQL PaaS (Managed Instance, DTU-model, vCore, Serverless, Hyperscale) the concept of named instance does not exist. Your best option is a SQL VM where you can run SQL Setup and install multiple instances.

It seems you need it for development purposes, then you may want to install SQL Server Developer Edition to avoid licensing costs as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/pricing-guidance#free-licensed-sql-server-editions). If this will be a Production server, remember to balance memory usage across the two SQL Server instances and leave some memory for the operating system to avoid impact on the server performance.